# VB.NET Using System.Threading.Volatile.Write on Enum var types

Tags: vb.net, enums, volatile

I am in need of performing a volatile write on a variable that is an Enum type derived from Byte, but I am stucked.

This is my (example) code:

```
Public Class MyOwnClass
    Friend Enum MyEnum As Byte
        Val1
        Val2
    End Enum

    Private MyEnumVar As MyEnum = MyEnum.Val1

    Friend Sub SetMyEnumVar(ByVal value As MyEnum)
        System.Threading.Volatile.Write(MyEnumVar, value) 'Error!
    End Sub
End Class
```

Since Threading.Volatile.Write is not provided with a signature with those arguments I get this error

```
  Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible Write can be called without a narrowing conversion:
```

With the list of all the overloads of the method.

CTyping the first argument is not working, because `CType` returns a casted value of course not with the same reference as `MyEnumVar` where the method gets the first parameter abviously `ByRef` instead.

`CObject` that would return a reference is also not viable because the method also hasn't got the overload for an object type other than `Write(Of T)(T, T)` where `T`must be a class type.

So how can I accomplish my purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volatile.Write Enum type in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031977/volatile-write-enum-type-in-vb-net)

Comment: Previous one removed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried the [Write(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712713(v=vs.110).aspx) overload? Something like `System.Threading.Volatile.Write(Of [Enum])(MyEnumVar, value)`.

Comment: (Of [enum]) did the magic, thank you! Didn't work with (Of MyEnum).

Comment: @Shockwaver Great! I posted it as an answer as others might find it useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Write(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712713(v=vs.110).aspx) overload where `T` is the type of `Enum`.

```vb
System.Threading.Volatile.Write(Of [Enum])(MyEnumVar, value)
```